# Python - comparing two lists of tuples

Tags: python, list

I have two lists of tuples (character, percentage) sorted by percentage. Ultimately, I need to keep appending characters to List_A until it reaches a predefined length (that logic has already been taken care of).

Example:

List_A

```
('a', 0.077)
('b', 0.070)
('c', 0.020)
('d', 0.015)
('z', 0.010)
```

List_B

```
('x', 0.060)
('y', 0.059)
('z', 0.055)
('a', 0.030)
('b', 0.010)
```

I need to:

1) Select a character from List_B and see if exists in List_A

2) If it does, calculate if it's percentage in List_B > it's percentage in List_A

3) If the percentage is greater, append that character to List_A

So, in this example, 'a' and 'b' won't ever get appended to List_A since List_B percentage < List_A percentage

'x' and 'y' won't ever get appended to List_A due to them not existing in List_A

'z' WILL get appended to List_A, likely multiple times, until it's percentage in List_A > the percentage in List_B

The looping and percentage logic has already been taken care of outside of this function. How do I apply these three conditions to these two lists?

Desired output of the above example would be List_A with another 'z' appended, something like:

```
('a', 0.077)
('b', 0.070)
('c', 0.020)
('d', 0.015)
('z', 0.010)
('z', 0.055)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Just make this a dictionary. It'll make your life easier. Also, please show us what you've done. You have nearly 100 reputation, so you should know by now SO is not a code writing service. You can keep listing your requirements until the cows come home but people will be much more receptive once you show you've genuinely tried to solve your own problems. For reference, please look at [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should create a dictionary mapping the characters in `List_A` to their percentage values. They are already in the right format (assuming no duplicates) so you can use the `dict` function. Then, iterate the elements in `List_B`, look up the values in the dictionary, and append them to the list. Also, don't forget to update the dictionary with the new (higher) percentages.

```
dict_a = dict(List_A)
for c, p in List_B:
    if c in dict_a and dict_a[c] < p:
        List_A.append((c, p))
        dict_a[c] = p
```

Comment: I think I see what you're doing, thank you for helping me out.